# unknown column in ' WHERE CLAUSE'

Tags: mysql

I have simple sql query

it should fetch the result but showing following error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'marital' in 'where clause'  0.000 sec

The column is present in the table

```
SELECT * FROM usa.adult
WHERE marital-status='Never-married'
AND gender='Male'
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably you do have an incorrect spelling of your column field, or simply that column does not exist in the first place. try to check first. And put a screenshot of your table schema if possible.

Comment: use `usa.fieldname` if you join multiple tables same way you did in  `usa.adult` and use backtick where (-) dash in field name, here is ``marital-status``

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe your column name is wrong, perhaps, it is `marital_status`? (use an underscore instead of a hyphen.
2. you can use `[marital-status]` or `'marital-status'`, if the column name is infact correct.

Please check your table schema and find the correct column name.

Answer (score 0):

The query should like this

```
   SELECT * FROM usa.adult
    WHERE `marital-status`='Never-married'
    AND gender='Male';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use marital_status rather than Marital-status. Use underscore because hyphen is not allowed.